# No se guardan los permisos en Laravel 6 con Caffeinated/Shinobi en la base de datos

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, users-roles, laravel-6, laravelcollective

Estoy haciendo el curso de Roles y Permisos y resulta que todo va bien menos la opción de actualizar los permisos. Al parecer las últimas actualizaciones del paquete shinobi han cambiado ciertas cosas al punto de que no se actualizan los permisos en la base de datos.

> Esta es la base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El controlador de roles y permisos según el tutorial actualiza los permisos del rol creado pero la verdad no me esta funcionando.

> En el RolController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Models\Role;
use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Models\Permission;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RolController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
      public function index()
    {
        $roles = Role::paginate();

        return view('roles.index', compact('roles'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $permissions = Permission::get();

        return view('roles.create', compact('permissions'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $role = Role::create($request->all());

        $role->permissions()->sync($request->get('permissions'));

        return redirect()->route('roles.edit', $role->id)
            ->with('info', 'Rol guardado con éxito');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $role = Role::find($id);

        return view('roles.show', compact('role'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $role = Role::find($id);

        $permissions = Permission::get();

        return view('roles.edit', compact('role', 'permissions'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $role = Role::find($id);
        $role->update($request->all());

        $role->permissions()->sync($request->get('permissions'));

        return redirect()->route('roles.edit', $role->id)
            ->with('info', 'Rol guardado con éxito');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $role = Role::find($id)->delete();

        return back()->with('info', 'Eliminado correctamente');
    }
}
```

> En la vista Blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  Role
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                {!! Form::model($role,
                    ['route' => ['roles.update', $role->id],
                   'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
                    {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'put') !!}





<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('name', 'Nombre del usuario')}}
    {{Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
       {{Form::label('slug', 'URL Amigable')}}
       {{Form::text('slug',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
       {{Form::label('description', 'Descripción')}}
       {{Form::textarea('description',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
</div>
<hr>
<h3>Permiso Especial</h3>
<div class="form-group">
       <label>{{Form::radio('special','all-access')}} Acceso Total</label>
       <label>{{Form::radio('special','no-access')}}  Ningun Acceso</label>


</div>

<hr>

<h3>Lista de Permisos</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
       <ul class="list-unstyled">
        @foreach($permissions as $permission)
          <li>
            <label>
                {{Form::checkbox('permission[]',$permission->id,null)}}
                {{$permission->name}}
                <em>({{$permission->description ? :'Sin descripción'}})</em>

            </label>

          </li>

        @endforeach
       </ul>

    </div>


<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::submit('Guardar',['class'=>'btn btn-sm btn-primary'])}}
</div>

                {!!Form::close()!!}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Por lo que entiendo el paquete Caffeinated/Shinobi ha cambiado ya muchos de los métodos. Pero en la nueva documentación no explica como funciona de esta manera.
Tampoco hay mucha documentación sobre como tener roles y permisos en una aplicación de Laravel.
Si alguno ha encontrado una solución para este problema y me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Ya encontre la solucion.

Comment: Guarda el rol con el método save() y luego asigna los permisos de la forma que lo estás haciendo, sincronizado.

Comment: Mario, si encontraste la solución considera añadir una respuesta a tu pregunta explicando cual fue, de esa manera podrás ayudar a otros que puedan tener tu mismo problema. Pasadas 48h, podrás aceptar tu propia respuesta.